# Integrar un tema en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

gusto en saludarlos. No se si este tema califique pero tengo una duda. Soy nuevo en rails. Compre un tema que me gustaba en Themeforest y lo quiero poner en mi app rails. Tiene todos los .JS y .CSS (No viene en scss). Me gustaría saber como integrarlo. He probado con Vendor/assets/  Los llamo en el application.scss con el @import cada uno de los css @import "style"; con los JS //= require jquery.easing por ejemplo.  No me resulta bien, los estilos quedan corridos, sera que la version de bootstrap que trae es diferente ?..

Alguna otra forma mas seguro de hacerlo?

Comment: Es algo complicado sin ver nada de código, pero tal vez mi primer intento sería, 1) poner todos los CSS en `app/assets/stylesheets`, llamarlos con `@import` desde `application.scss` 2) JavaScript en `app/assets/javascripts`, sin llamarlos deberían estar incluidos en automático sólo por estar ahí. 3) A partir de Rails 5.1, jQuery no está incluido automáticamente, así que lo tienes que agreagar a tu App, además en caso de que uses Turbolinks (lo normal en una nueva app en rails) tu JS deberá estar dentro de `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... }` . Espero que esto te sea útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El único problema que hay al implementar un template en rails, es la ruta de las imágenes o de algún archivo externo (e.j. imágenes, PDFs, etc.).
Con los demás archivos (html, css, js) no hay problema, solo debes ponerlos en los assets, cada uno tiene una carpeta creada respectivamente, no hace falta importarlos puesto que en el application.js o application.css importas el tree que incluye todos los archivos en dicha carpeta, por lo tanto solo deberías copiar tus archivos ahí.

Puede que tengas problemas con el orden en que se cargan los archivos, por lo tanto te recomiendo que los renombres, de tal manera que queden en el mismo orden que están incluidos en el template, esto para los archivos JS y CSS.

Luego te corresponde cambiar las etiquetas HTML regulares como por ejemplo IMG y usar la etiqueta nativa de rails (<%= image_tag 'nombre.extención' %>), pues esto optimiza el uso del framework, y tiene ciertas ventajas.

Comment: Muchas gracias,  Hare esto, es un poco tedioso pero igual me ayuda a entender todo el codigo.